# Change to a Root directory in Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I need to `run` a file in the `/opt` folder. I am currently in the `/home` directory (a root peer of /opt) and cannot seem to do anything there, presumably because the EC2-user account is not a true root account.

How can I run a file in the /opt directory from the /home directory.

I have tried `sudo /opt/ejabberd-18.01/bin/ejabberdctl start` and get:
`sudo /opt/ejabberd-18.01/bin/ejabberdctl: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

`/opt` is owned by root. You need to make the file executable by you. It's not exactly much trouble. It's one command:

`sudo chmod +x filename`

Hope it helps